# Github action deploy-cloud-functions not building in dependencies?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, dependencies, github-actions

Yesterday, I was trying to restructure some Github CI/CD, because the actions from Google were throwing warnings about deprecated usages.

One of the steps is the (build and) deployment of a GCP function.
The repository of the function to be deployed was structured like this:

```
my_proj
  |- .github
  |- src
     |- my_proj
        |- __init__.py
        |- main.py
        |- requirements.txt
...
```

,with the requirements.txt holding

```
boto3==1.16.54
```

The important bit here is the requirements.txt, that holds some dependencies, that I need to ship as well.

Before, I had to build the package uploaded to GCP myself, but with the "[deploy-cloud-functions](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions)" action this seemed to be obsolete now. I set up the actions in Github according to documentation:

```
steps:
  - name: Login to GCP
    uses: google-github-actions/auth@v0
    with:
      credentials_json: ...

  - name: Deploy GCP Function image
    uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@v0
    with:
      name: my_function_name
      runtime: python37
      project_id: ...
      source_dir: ./src/my_proj
      env_vars:
        ...
```

Now, the deployment worked. However, when inspecting the function now in GCP or downloading it, none of the dependencies were contained there and the logs upon triggering the function similarly showed a function crash due to missing dependencies.

I also tried to move the requirements.txt file to the project root, but apparently to no avail. I was not very lucky in finding extensive documentation about the work with GCP functions from within Github beyond the above linked Google-owned action repository.

Can anyone spot my error here?

Comment: Can you post your requirements.txt file? Are you using some private dependencies?

Comment: Btw, you won't be able to see your dependencies binaries in the source tab, but you will be able to see the Build log if you look for `resource.type="build"` in the Cloud Logging console

Comment: I added my requirements.txt content, which is not crazy. I'll check out your suggestion in the Cloud console. Thank you very much!

Comment: I see the build statements in the logs! Huzzah! Guess, I'll go back to experimenting with it. Thank you so much, @DanyelCabello !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While deploying to Cloud Functions using [github actions](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions) all the dependencies also get uploaded. But, as already mentioned by **Danyel Cabello**, you won’t be able to see the dependencies in the source tab of the Cloud Functions in Google Cloud Console.

To see the build logs you can search for `resource.type=“build”` in the Cloud Logging of Google Cloud Console.